# Digit Sum in Python with user input

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
def digit_sum(n):
    total = 0
    while True:
        a = n % 10
        n = n // 10
        total = total + a
        if n < 1 :
            break
    return total

print digit_sum(12584521)
```

In the code above I want to allow the user to input a number. For example, a user inputs 12584521, then hits *enter* and the result appears (in this example the result is 28). How do I modify my code above to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you miss "input".       input('please enter a number:')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
print digit_sum(input("enter num: "))
```

For python2.x and 3.x

```
print(digit_sum(int(input("enter num: "))))
```

Answer (score 2):

For python 3.x , you can use the `input()` function . Example -

```
num = int(input("Please enter a number :"))
```

The above would prompt the user  - `Please enter a number :` , and then wait for them to input and press `enter` .

Documentation for this and others can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html).

For Python 2.x , it is better to use - `raw_input()` , instead of `input()` , because in python 2.x , input would actually try to execute what ever was inputted.

Example for python 2.x -

```
num = int(raw_input("Please enter a number :"))
```

Comment: You would have to adapt your code to print it out, by calling `digit_sum(num)`

Answer (score -1):

```
inputDigit = int(input()) #take input
```

`inputDigit = int(raw_input())` #in python 2.7

Here is the working example [Ideone](https://ideone.com/yB7WK3)

Comment: is this even python language?